# iOS Dropbox API "not currently support by MPOAuthConnection" occur after changing user

Tags: objective-c, ios, oauth, dropbox-api

I am trying to use Dropbox API on iOS but I got trapped by the error when I try to use `loadMetadata` method.

process flow is below..

---

1.link (UserA)

```
[[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
```

2.allow authorization on dropbox authorization view

3.unlink (UserA)

```
[[DBSession sharedSession] unlinkAll];
```

4.link (UserB)

```
[[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
```

5.allow authorization on dropbox authorization view

6.loadMetadata

```
[[self restClient] loadMetadata:path];
```

But here I get the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Unsupported Signature Method', reason: 
'The signature method "(null)" is not currently support by MPOAuthConnection'
```

---

`loadMetaData` did work correctly as `UserA` but it did not work after changing user.

I doubt that the way to `unlink` could be not enough .. but I do not know.

Please give me any advices in order to solve the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I've got it solved thanks to this > https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=94511#post-517526

Answer (score 5):

- Migrating the answer above to a proper one.... As @yusaku posted in a comment on his question, this link has the answer: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=94511#post-517526

Specifically, Greg K. says:

> Make sure you clear all your DBRestClient objects when you unlink. If
>   you try to use an old DBRestClient object it will cause this problem.

Clearing the old DBRestClient should be a no-brainer, but when it's late and you're following sample code that makes it a persistent class variable, it's easy to skip a brain or two.

Comment: Both dropbox forum links above are dead but Mr. Fire's answer is correct - The actual issue is likely that once you've initialized a DBRestClient, it continues to try to use the same user ID for authentication throughout its lifespan. If you unlink that user (even if you've added another user instead), it will fail to authenticate API calls because it no longer has credentials for that user.

The fix is to create a new DBRestClient when you switch to a new user.